# PostgreSQL WAL for PITR recover

Tags: postgresql, point-in-time-recovery

I don't think my question makes any sense with the answer, but simply to confirm my doubt? I understand that PITR recovery is done with logs from the same database release (this is what I learned in the IBM Db2 LUW database concept).

But my doubt is, If I restore the backup of the PostgreSQL instance from source server to the destination where the database version of the source is Postgres 13 and the destination server running on PostgreSQL 14. Is it possible to use WAL from a lower version to a higher version for PIT recovery in the PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Backup and Restore across versions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/269019/backup-and-restore-across-versions)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Not only can you ***not*** do PITR recovery to a different version, you can't even restore a physical backup onto a different version, or even a different OS/architecture with the same version.

To do cross version restoring, you would need a logical backup, and you can't do PITR with one of those.

You could restore to the same version, do PITR there, then use pg_upgrade to upgrade the already recovered database to the (newer) version you want to use.